# Karate: Azuredevops: How to display all the test method names in junit result files

Tags: karate

How to display all test method names that were mentioned in runner.java files. I see only testParallel method name. [image]

Below is my folder structure. In each module I have feature files and then the runner.java file. My question is how to display the test method names which are in runner.java file in the reports when we run as suite. For example I hae a SitesRunner.java file and I do have a method as below

```
@Karate.Test
Karate testGetAllSites() {
    return new Karate().feature("getsites").relativeTo(getClass());
}
```

How to display the method name testGetAllSites in the attached pipeline devops report?

[image]

Comment: voting to close this question for poor detail. but read this please: https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution

Comment: Hi @PeterThomas I have updated the question.

Comment: it doesn't help at all. azure probably looks for the JUnit XML. the docs tell you where it will be output. now this is an azure question nothing to do with karate

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong runner. Please read the docs and understand how to use the parallel runner. Only that will emit the XML and JSON files that CI tools will use.

Link: https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution